# Comparing two matrices with eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Let's say I have two eigen matrices A and B, and I want to create a third matrix defined by

C(i,j) = 5.0 if A(i,j) > B(i,j), 0 otherwise

I guess it is possible to do it without an explicit for loop. But I am not very proficient with Eigen yet. What whould be the best approach?

Comment: How is matrix `>` defined again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `A`, `B` and `C` are `MatrixXd` you can do:

```
C = (A.array()>B.Array()).cast<double>() * 5.0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this `cast<double>()`. I was not aware of such a method.