# How to compare 2 matrices?

Tags: c++, eigen

Before anything else I must say that I've studied [Comparing two matrices with eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228332/comparing-two-matrices-with-eigen)
 but my question is not the same. Suppose I have two eigen matrices A and B, and I want to edit A in following way:

> if (A(i,j) > B(i,j))    A(i,j) = A(i,j)
>   otherwise    A(i,j) = B(i,j)

I guess it is possible to do it without an explicit for loop. But I am not very proficient with Eigen yet. What whould be the best approach?

Comment: I am not into Eigen but a general way to express such a thing goes along the way of A = A*(A > B) + B*(B > A).

Comment: Does `a = (a > b) ? a : b` work at all?

Comment: @AlanStokes I don't think that would work, as you/Eigen cannot overload ternary operator.

Comment: @AlanStokes It doesn't work in Eigen.

Comment: @ypnos Good point. I was trying to figure out what this was for: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1CwiseTernaryOp.html (the documentation seems unhelpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`A.cwiseMax(B)`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#a1203d5f97d7de30b5aab64aed891536e).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix2i A = Eigen::Matrix2i::Random();
    Eigen::Matrix2i B = Eigen::Matrix2i::Random();

    std::cout << "A =\n" << A << "\nB =\n" << B << "\n";

    A = A.cwiseMax(B);

    std::cout << "max(A,B) =\n" << A << "\n";
}
```

Output on my machine is

```
A =
 730547559  607950953
-226810938  640895091
B =
 884005969 -353856438
-649503489  576018668
max(A,B) =
 884005969  607950953
-226810938  640895091
```